# Stop youtube video autoplay in Firefox v47

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I write HTML code and javascript like

```
 <div class="img-left video-box" style="margin-right:0;">
                <div onclick="this.nextSibling.style.display='block'; this.style.display='none'"><img src="images/article-0418/video6.jpg" style="width:338px; height:192px; cursor:pointer" /></div><div style="display:none;">
                    <object width="340" height="192"><param name="movie" value="//www.youtube.com/v/jt4uCULmGFE ?version=3&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="//www.youtube.com/v/jt4uCULmGFE?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0&autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="340" height="192" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>                    
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want to click on image and then play video but in firefox v47 or some new versions it play automatically in background.
but this code working fine in firefox v39.

Thanxs

Answer (score 0):

```
 <param name="autoplay" value="false">
```

Try adding this param 'autoplay' and set its value to false.